# In "success is counted sweetest", why does the verb 'counted' follow the adjective 'sweetest'?

Tags: grammar

The question comes from a poem by Emily Dickinson:

> Success is counted sweetest
> By those who ne’er succeed.
> To comprehend a nectar
> Requires sorest need.

In 'success is counted sweetest', why does the verb 'counted' follow the adjective 'sweetest'? Usually a verb should follow an adverb, not an adjective.

Comment: Stating the obvious: in that poem, the verb "counted" _doesn't_ follow the adjective "sweetest", the adjective follows the verb. And that's quite common and normal: "I am hot"; "I feel angry"; "He became powerful".

Comment: you means 'count' can be classified  into linking verb ,does it? But  I can't  find such meaning in a dictionary

Comment: It's not _quite_ the same, but "count" can mean [to consider as](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/count) eg "I count myself fortunate".

Comment: It's an object-orientated depictive construction, passivised here. 'I/We/They count success sweetest [ie the sweetest thing possible] [...]'. // cf  'I reckon Sir Galahad the boldest'  ↔ 'Sir Galahad is/was reckoned the boldest.' [passive transformation]